# Rails link_to with font-awesome and external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm trying to link to a youtube page in a rails app with the font-awesome gem.

```
<i><%= link_to fa_icon "youtube-square 2x", @book.youtube %></i>
```

In doing so, I receive `no implicit conversion of Symbol into String` error message.

Do I need to remove the font-awesome helper and include it as a class, or is there another way to make this work together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Looking at the docs](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers), I believe that you need to put the `fa_icon` helper in a `link_to` block:

```
<%= link_to @book.youtube do %>
    <%= fa_icon "youtube-square 2x" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I did not see this in the docs.  May I ask where you found this information?

Comment: @JustinGrant Click on the "Looking at the docs" link and it will open you the gem documentation on github (here's the link just for case - https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers )